# Is the area too small for JPopupMenu?

Tags: java, swing, popup, jframe, jpopupmenu

In the last question I was asking the community why my `JPopupMenu` did not appear on the screen.
I was unable to come up with a simple , runnable, compilable example.
So, here is what I did for you guys:
[image]

Is the area too small to draw a popup?

I want my popup to be like this:
[image: pop]
The code of what I did is visible in the first photo.

#### Code:

```
/* The old code entered here has been removed */
```

Complete code can be [found here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BzY15ZB0eWxFTFEyWk1RQWRwVkk)

#### edit 2

I copied the various `JRadioButtonMenuItem` and the `setupJPopup()` into a new file and ran. It works. Why doesn't it work in ScreenRecorder class?
**Code**
package demo;

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class PopupTrial {


    public PopupTrial(){
        setupJPopup();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                new PopupTrial();
            }
        });
    }
    public void setupJPopup(){
        encodingGroup.add(avi);
        encodingGroup.add(quicktime);

        popup.add(avi);
        popup.add(quicktime);
        popup.addSeparator();

        recordingAreaGroup.add(entireScreen);
        recordingAreaGroup.add(custom);

        popup.add(entireScreen);
        popup.add(custom);
        popup.addSeparator();

        cursorGroup.add(selectBlackCursor);
        cursorGroup.add(selectWhiteCursor);
        cursorGroup.add(selectNoCursor);

        selectCursor.add(selectBlackCursor);
        selectCursor.add(selectWhiteCursor);
        selectCursor.add(selectNoCursor);

        popup.add(selectCursor);
        popup.pack();
    }
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Click Me");
    ButtonGroup recordingAreaGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup cursorGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup encodingGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
    JRadioButtonMenuItem avi = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("AVI",true);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem quicktime = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("QuickTime",false);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem entireScreen = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Entire Screen",true);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem custom = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Custom...",false);
    JMenuItem selectCursor = new JMenu("Select a cursor");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem selectWhiteCursor = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("White Cursor",true);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem selectBlackCursor = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Black Cursor",false);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem selectNoCursor = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("No Cursor",false);
}
```

[image]

Comment: in the screenshot there is no code related to `JPopupMenu`

Comment: @LittleChild: please post code, not screenshots; an sscce is best; for reference, I've cited on below.

Comment: @trashgod: Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0BzY15ZB0eWxFRC16T1VIZkJtNVE/edit). `Stack Stuff->Prorotype->src->demo->Screen Recorder.txt`

Comment: @trashgod I copied the same code into a new file, compiled and ran. it did. I don't know why it won't run in my Screen Recorder

Comment: There are several ways that re-factoring can leave an out-of-date class file in the project; a full build is the expedient course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the size of the `JFrame` isn't related to why the `PopupMenu` isn't showing.  Here's an example showing something similar to what you want (and using similar methods) working:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PopupMenu extends Box{

    Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(400,30);

    public PopupMenu(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        final JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu("Options");
        for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
            menu.add(new JMenuItem("Option" + i));

        JLabel clickMe = new JLabel("ClickMe");
    clickMe.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        clickMe.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }});

        add(clickMe);       
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return preferredSize;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new PopupMenu());
        frame.validate();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `Box`; DYM `clickMe.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT)` and `add(Box.createHorizontalGlue())`?

Comment: @trashgod - Oy Vey! I'm so tired this morning I couldn't think of the right syntax for alignment (even though I've used it hundreds of times) and forgot to take out my attempts before posting.  Thanks for the help - I fixed the code (I was mostly looking for alignmentX).